# Update table column spetial ordering and grouping

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a table W_PHOTO and doc_id is null, I want to update doc_id, group by type_id, but next type_id don't the same it new doc_id, for example

```
   id      case    type_id     pnum      doc_id
1000001  1000001    2101        20          1
1000002  1000001    2101        40          1
1000003  1000001    2101        60          1
1000004  1000001    106         70          2
1000005  1000001    106         80          2
1000006  1000001    1199        100         3
1000007  1000001    1103        120         4
1000008  1000001    7           140         5
1000009  1000001    106         160         6
1000010  1000001    2103        180         7
1000011  1000001    2105        200         8
1000012  1000001    2106        220         9
1000013  1000001    2104        240         10
1000014  1000001    2202        260         11
1000015  1000001    1104        280         12
1000016  1000001    103         310         13
1000017  1000001    103         320         13
1000018  1000001    103         340         13
1000019  1000001    1199        380         14
1000020  1000001    2104        400         15
1000021  1000001    2104        420         15
1000022  1000001    2104        440         15
1000023  1000001    2104        460         15
```

Comment: on what what basis do you need to increment doc_id?

Comment: incriment doc_id grup by type_id, but next type_id don't the same it new doc_id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `lag` to compare the current row's type_id with the previous row and then use running sum to assign the same number to consecutive rows with the same type_id value.

```
select t.*,sum(col) over(order by id) as doc_id
from (select t.*,
      case when type_id=lag(type_id) over(order by id) then 0 else 1 end as col
      from t
     ) t
```

Comment: I had the same thought..I am not fast enough to formulate the query though:)